# How to pull data from an array in Firestore?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The data that I am drawing out of Cloud Firestore works successfully but I'm unsure of how to draw data from an array in my database

I've never used the map/array feature in firestore and I have been struggling to figure out how use it even after reading the documentation

How would I be able to restructure my data to pull data from the array?

This first image is what I've been drawing data successfully from: 
[image: data draw]

But I'm trying to use the map/array function to draw out the data from weight and price in Firestore:
[image: array data]

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Stuff {

    var documentID: String
    var name: String
    var brand: String
    var price: Int
    var weight: String
}

extension Stuff: DocumentSerializable {

    init(name: String,
         brand: String,
         weight: String,
         price: Int) {
             let document = Firestore.firestore().stuff.document()
             self.init(documentID: document.documentID,
                       name: name,
                       brand: brand,
                       price: price,
                       weight: weight)
   }

   private init?(documentID: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
       guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
           let brand = dictionary["brand"] as? String,
           let weight = dictionary["weight"] as? String,
           let price = dictionary["price"] as? Int else { return nil }

           self.init(documentID: documentID,
                     name: name,
                     brand: brand,
                     price: price,
                     weight: weight)
   }

   init?(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
       self.init(documentID: document.documentID, dictionary: document.data())
   }

   init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
       guard let data = document.data() else { return nil }
       self.init(documentID: document.documentID, dictionary: data)
   }

   var documentData: [String: Any] {
       return [
             "name": name,
             "brand": brand,
             "weight": weight,
             "price": price
              ]
    }

}
```

Comment: From your screenshot and code, I don't see any arrays or lists.  You have two map type fields in `price` and `weight`.  Those maps would just be read and written with a dictionary.  I believe the duplicate shows that you cast the field value to `[String: Any]`.

Comment: ive been testing it its just not working correctly, could you show me an example to structure it better? since the example you gave me isn't really helpful and ive tried using it before with no success

Comment: The code you're showing isn't working correctly because you're trying to cast a dictionary to a string.  Instead, cast the map fields (both weight and price) to a dictionary as shown in the dup.  Then access the fields of the dictionary as you've named them in your map.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay I will run tests to see if can make it work, if I can't figure out how to do this correctly would you mind helping me?

Comment: If you have new code that exhibits new errors that are different than what you have now, you should post a new question with a description of what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: You can probably just update this question to make what you're asking more clear. I think you're asking how to read the price and weight fields but it's not clear what issue you're having with doing that. But as Doug mentions above, there's code that's unrelated to doing that; for example `let weight = dictionary["weight"] as? String` is a string but the weight field in your screen shot is an array of indexes with Int's as their value.